# Creating Spark job in Data Lake instead of a U-SQL job

Tags: azure, apache-spark, u-sql

Is it possible to create Spark job in Data Lake instead of a U-SQL job ?

Comment: Have you considered using on-demand HDInsight clusters to execute a Spark job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the options for big data services in Azure:

- **Azure Data Lake Analytics** currently has only **U-SQL** jobs and not Spark.
- **Azure HDInsight** supports Spark jobs.
- **Azure Databricks** supports Spark jobs.
- **Cloudera on Azure ** supports Spark jobs.
- **Hortonworks on Azure ** supports Spark jobs.